# struct self referencing

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm having syntax error everywhere, bad understanding of syntax for ADTs and memory handling. I need a struct that references to itself (other sections) in the `next` and `prev`. Am I doing it right? I get errors...

```
struct _header * header;

typedef struct _header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    header_t* next;
    header_t* prev;
} header;
```

I also want to initialise the first 32 bytes within the memory with a header (this is not going well also..):

```
//this is to reference the memory block later
static int *free_list_ptr;

void function(u_int32_t size){
    memory = (byte*) malloc(size);
    header firstHead = malloc(sizeof(_header));
   free_list_ptr = firstHead = memory;
   firstHead->prev = free_list_ptr;
   firstHead->next = free_list_ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't reference a `typedef` while creating it, so you should do:

```
typedef struct a_header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    struct a_header* next;
    struct a_header* prev;
} header;

header* the_header;
```

Avoid names with leading underscore - they are reserved for the system things.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
typedef struct _header *lpheader;

typedef struct _header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    lpheader next;
    lpheader prev;
} header, *lpheader;
```

Also why do you need 32 bytes worth of space for this structure? You should rather be using `sizeof(_header)`.

Comment: @Havelock agreed but this is going to wreck havoc unless every element in struct is of 8bytes. :P

Answer (score 0):

This is your current problem.

```
memory = (byte*) malloc(size); 
header firstHead = malloc(sizeof(header)); 
    free_list_ptr = firstHead = memory;
```

You allocate `size` and store its location as a `byte*` into `memory`.

Then you (correctly) allocate one `header` structure, and store that space's allocation into `firstHead`.

Then you throw that away (leaking that memory) by setting `firstHead` to the wrongly sized allocated space of `memory`, and then set `free_list_ptr` to the same wrongly sized allocated space.

Since your current pointer isn't holding enough memory, you get into trouble when you try to use the offsets of `next` and `prev`.

I suspect you need this:

```
memory = null; 
header firstHead = malloc(sizeof(header)); 
memory = free_list_ptr = firstHead;
```

This will set the pointers `memory` and `free_list_ptr` to both point at the allocated space pointed at by `firstHead`.

I don't know why you are using two different pointers to track `memory` and `free_list_ptr`. My intuition is that 1 of these are probably sufficent for your purposes.

Comment: if i change the size allocation to _header it would work right?

Comment: I've updated my post with what I think you need. In summary, you need to have `memory` NOT allocate space you aren't going to use, and set it and `free_list_ptr`to the `firstHead`.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking too complicated, your `typedef` is too late and you are using the wrong name inside the declaration of the `struct`.

```
typedef struct header header; // <- forward declare "struct header" and identifier "header"

struct header {
    int signiture;
    int size;
    header* next;
    header* prev;
};
```

For the sequel, I didn't really understand what you wanted to do. What is for sure that you use bizarre names in there that aren't declared and that you cast the return of `malloc`.